# Error:android-apt-compiler: Cannot run program "sdk_path/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt": java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied

Tags: android, intellij-idea, aapt

I'm using **Intellij IDEA 14.1.2**, java version "`1.6.0_45`" and `OS Ubuntu 14.04 32bit`,
Showing this error during execution.

> Error:android-apt-compiler: Cannot run program
>   "sdk_path/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt": java.io.IOException: error=13,
>   Permission denied

May I know you how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

right click on 'aapt' file , properties -> permissions and check 'Allow executing file as program'. then close the window. in my case,after giving permission for 'aapt' file, i had to give the same permission for 'dx' and 'zipalign' files in the same directory (.../build-tools/21.1.2/)

See if this solves your problem.

Comment: I did as per your direction changed at all 3 file you mentioned above.. now rebuild project.. still its showing  " **ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb" and click 'Restart'** "

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I just started and I get: com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessNotCreatedException: Cannot run program "/Users/newuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator": error=13, Permission denied